# Determing inverse Z-transform using impulse response?

Tags: matlab, z-transform, impulse-response

In Matlab there is a command `iztrans` for finding inverse Z-transform. But how can we find inverse Z-transform using impulse response? The Matlab command `impz` gives Impulse response of digital filter but how can I then proceed towards finding inverse Z-transform?  Actually i want to determine inverse ztransform of H(z) shown in attached photo. But i want to determine inverse z transform using impulse response since i read somewhere that inverse ztransform can be determined by impulse response using matlab but i am unable to find any google resource that guides much in this regard. I have also attached a table of common z tranforms. I have also highlighted the two most relevant cases as far answer of GKH is concerned

[image]

[image: ztransform table]

Comment: Could you explain what the question is? inverse z-transform of *what* for what purpose? I honestly don't think your question makes much sense – the impulse response already *is* in time domain, and what you'd typically do with an inverse z-transform is transform something from z-domain to time domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an $H(z)$ (a transfer function), its inverse Z-transform **is** the impulse response $h[n]$. `iztrans` is a symbolic function to compute any (causal) inverse Z-transform, either it is related to an impulse response or not. `impz` is a non-symbolic function to compute some samples of the impulse response of a digital filter.

If I were you and I wanted to find the inverse Z-transform of the given $H(z)$ - which **is** the impulse response -  I would use `residuez`:

```
[r,p,k] = residuez([4 3 9], [4 3 -4])
r =

 1.0544
 2.1956


p =

-1.4430
 0.6930


k =

 -2.2500
```

That allows you to write the impulse response as $$h[n] \approx -2.25\delta[n] + 1.0544(-1.443)^nu[n] + 2.1956(0.693)^nu[n] $$

given that we're talking about a causal system.

Alternatively, you can use

```
[h,n] = impz([4 3 9], [4 3 -4]);
```

but that will give you only a couple of samples of the impulse response.

Comment: how did you write equation/formula for h[n]?i mean how did you define that h[n] is equal to dirac_delta(k)+r1(p1)^n*u[n]+r2(p2)^n*u[n] ??

Comment: That is how this function works. Type `help residuez` to check it. It returns a partial fraction expansion of a rational transfer function.

Comment: "If I were you and I wanted to find the inverse Z-transform of the given H(z) - which is the impulse response - I would use '''residuez''':"  Does your this use of '''residuez'' will be valid for both causal and non causal as well as anti causal inverse z transforms?

Comment: "iztrans is a symbolic function to compute any (causal) inverse Z-transform". It means,we cannot use it for noncausal and anticausal cases?

Comment: Regarding `residuez`, the causal/non-causal/anti-causal interpretation is up to you. The function only performs Partial Fraction Expansion. Finding the impulse response is entirely up to you, according to the ROC of the system you're studying. So actually, the equation for $h[n]$ I derived could be different.

Regarding `iztrans`, as far as I know for MATLAB and Octave, it works for causal signals only.